# ¿Cómo mandar información de query, por medio de metodo POST en un formulario oculto?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual me muestra los registros de personas  apartir de un query. Quiero mandar por medio de la funcion ***post*** el ***id_Persona*** por medio de un formulario oculto, y se mande a página idsPersonas.php cachando solo el id_Persona

Lo hice de esta manera el código para mandar llamar la función *post*

```
<tr class='clickable-row' onclick="post('/idsPersonas.php/',{ids: <?php "$lista[id_Persona];" ?>});">
```

Al momento de ver la pagina, me manda a una página `undefined`.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Este es mi código:

```
             <table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead class="text-primary">
                            <tr >

                                <th class="cabezera"><center><h4>Fecha</h4></center></th>
                                <th class="cabezera"><center><h4>Hora</h4></center></th>
                                <th class="cabezera"><center><h4>Nombre</h4></center></th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                            <?php
                                if(count($listado)> 0 ){
                                    foreach($listado as $lista) 
                                {
                                $cuenta++;              
                            ?> 
                        <tbody>

                            <tr class='clickable-row' onclick="post('/idsPersonas.php/',{ids: <?php "$lista[id_Persona];" ?>});">

                                <td><?php printf("%s",$lista["Fecha"]);  ?></td>
                                <td><?php printf("%s",$lista["Hora"]);  ?></td>
                                <td><?php printf("%s",$lista["Nombre"]);  ?></td>

                            </tr> 
                            <?php     
                                }
                                    }else {
                            ?> 
                            <h3> No hay </h3>
                            <?php
                                }//fin else 
                                //printf($cuenta_eventos);  
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Codigo JS:

```
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.
    console.log(method);

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: no entiendo porque recorres con un for los params? no te conviene usar getAttribute para obtener los elementos?

Answer (score 0):

Si pones los parametros dentro de un data tag, y los traes adentro de la funcion no te sirve mas?
despues debes jugar con los array de datos si es que mandas varios ids de persona por fila que veo que es lo que queres hacer.

```
<tr class='clickable-row' onclick="post(this);" data-form-method="POST" data-form-uri="idsPersonas.php" data-form-idPersona="<?php "$lista[id_Persona];" ?>">

function post(elmnt) {

        var method = elmnt.getAttribute('data-form-method');
        var path = elmnt.getAttribute('data-form-uri');
        var idPersona = elmnt.getAttribute('data-form-idPersona');
        //method = method || "post";
        console.log(method);

        // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
        // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
        var form = document.createElement("form");

        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);

        for(var key in params) {
            if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
             }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
```

Comment: solo se debe mandar un id de persona, y cacharlo en idsPersonas.php, probe tu codigo, pero sigo con el mismo problema de al clickear `<tr>` me redirige a _undefined_